# How to find duplicate child nodes having more than one parent in a file system?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-algorithm

In a custom made, in memory file system my files and directories are in the form of a tree where the directories have references to the child nodes which can be either a directory or a file.
I can do add , remove, delete , move operation over the files and directories. Now due to a bug somehow whenever a file is moved from a parent node to another parent node its reference is not removed from the earlier parent node.

**Example**

```
D1 (parent ) C1 ( child )
after move
D1 (parent ) C1 (child)
D2 (parent ) C1 (child)
```

**Question:**
Now the question is what is the most optimal way to find out all such files , which have duplicate parents ? Right now I am keeping all the file references in a global hashset , which guess will be a pain if I have a huge set of files ?

**Note:** : Parent is aware of all its children but a child is not aware of its parent.

**Approach taken so far:** The approach I am thinking of is to first traverse though the whole directory structure and then keep all the file references in a hashset and before inserting any value to the hashset I will check if it already exists, if yes then this is a corrupt file having duplicate parent nodes .

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class RecursiveFiles {
    private static Set<File> set = new HashSet<File>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File root = new File("C:\\Windows\\Help");
        showFiles(root);
    }

    private static void showFiles(File root) {
        if(root.isDirectory()){
            File[] children = root.listFiles();
            for(File child : children){
                showFiles(child);
            }   
        }else {
            if(set.contains(root)){
                System.out.println("Duplicate File " + root);   
            }else {
                set.add(root);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If think of files as nodes and parenthood as edges then you can use bfs/dfs algorithms but with a little change, instead of a boolean visited state, use a list of visited for each node, and in the list keep all the parent address that visited this node. Also consider that your graph is a direct graph so no one can visit his parent.